# All objects are invisible

Tags: game-engine, physics

I was working on a game, but when I play it, all objects are invisible. It turns out, they all have the invisible property in the physics tab enabled. I don't know when it happened, and there's a lot of objects so turning them all visible again would be a nightmare.

Is there a way to do it to make all objects visible again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an incredibly easy way to do this using the outliner. All objects with the  "invisible" property enabled will have the render icon faded out. Instead of selecting all your objects and manually turning off "invisible" on all of them, you can simple click the render icon in the outliner to re-enable visibility.

[image]

Comment: you can change that property for listed objects (on or off) in a single move, keeping pressed LMB and dragging over the desired icons in the outliner

Answer (score 2):

Select the objects and press Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> on the keyboard.

You likely did 'restrict render' which is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Also worth knowing is <kbd>H</kbd> to hide from the viewport and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to unhide all.

Comment: yep, this will also work, (but will unhide Everything in the scene)